# Error in plugin 'run-sequence(sass) while installing elixir in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm very new in laravel, I was just trying to install elixir in laravel 5.2, I followed all the steps that they have provided in the docs, but I'm getting error when I run the gulp command it says:

> Error in plugin 'run-sequence(sass)'
>
> Message:
>       %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>   \?\C:\xampp\htdocs\fresh\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-sass\nod
>   e_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-46\binding.node

I've searched it but I didn't get much help from it. Can anybody please guide me?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue